# How to apply where clause on nested queries in graphQl/Sequelize?

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, where-clause, subquery

I have the following Menu Model with a nested structure:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  …   
type Menu{
        id:Int
        label: String
        children: [Menu]
        icon: String
        table: String
    }
…
```

This model is resolved as follows:

```
const resolvers = {
…
   Query: {
      nodes: async (_, args,context) =>{
        try{
…
            const menu=await Menu.findAll({ where: args});
                    return menu;
            } catch(error){
                console.error("ERROR");
                return {};
            }
        },
…
    Menu: {
        children: async(menu) => {
            const getM=await menu.getMenus();
            return getM;
        },
    },  
…
```

It works as requested until I needed to apply some restrictions on the menu access.
Let us consider that I want to restrict the access to id #5 of Menu. The following works for the first level but not for children.

```
const menu=await Menu.findAll({ where: {...args,[Op.not]:{id:5}}});
```

I understand that getMenus() is directly executed by Sequelize without recalling the resolver but how to apply the “where clause” for children or how to let getMenus() consider the constraint of the “where clause”?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use include to include the childs (menus) and there add the where clause. Like this:

```
const result: ParentEntity = await ParentEntity.schema(tenant).findAll<ParentEntity>({
        include: [{
          model: ChildEntity.schema(tenant),
          where: yourConditionOnTheChildEntity
        }]
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However it didn't work. In fact, it still only acts on the first level while adding a constraint that the children exist and verify the where clause.